# Where is the "Enable UEV" setting in Windows 10 Group Policy?

Tags: windows-10, group-policy

I cannot locate the GPO setting for enabling UEV for Windows 10 1607+. I would like to enable this setting so the default UEV service is enabled on our deployments.

- We have the latest admx files from MS for UEV (UserExperienceVirtualization.admx 25/04/2017)
- I am using the Win10 RSAT tools on a Win10 LTSB (don't ask) deployment.
- I can see the "Enable UEV" settings through local group policy on the PC.

When navigating to the appropriate GPO area (Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Microsoft User Experience Virtualization), the "Enable UEV" settings does not exist.

I have researched the MS documentation which doesn't explain why it would be missing. Other sites do not seem to reference this issu, all sites simply say that the setting should be set and assume that it is available. It seems I meet all criteria I can find to have access to this setting, but clearly I must be missing something.

Comment: Are you sure `UserExperienceVirtualization.admx` supports 1607?  The date of the file indicates, `UserExperienceVirtualization.admx` only supports 1703 and newer.  After you verify the .admx applies to 1607 edit your question.

Comment: I can't find any reference that it doesn't apply to 1607 and only applies to 1703. Can you share your reference? It would be very much appreciated. The MDOP ADMX templates download site only cites Windows 10 as a requirement, and the "getting started/what's new" doesn't state it either. Of course the MS documentation is the usual minefield for trying to get correct info. So at the moment I can't verify that the ADMX does or does not apply.

Comment: I have copied the admx/adml files from the 1607 device, and the settings shows. I would prefer to use a _published_ admx, I am surprised that the newer one does not allow this setting on older devices since it is present. I would still like to find the reference you mention. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the information required: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35333.ue-v-important-changes-in-ue-v-functionality-after-the-windows-10-anniversary-update.aspx

> The Group Policy ADMX for UE-V is included in Windows 10 Anniversary update.  **You can find the file in C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions\UserExperienceVirtualization.admx**.  See Configuring UE-V with Group Policy Objects Jump for more details.
>
> The Anniversary Update introduces support for Microsoft Office 2016 templates, as well as **a new value named EnableUEV**.

So it would seem the ADMX templates provided with MDOP appear to be more for Windows versions lower than 1607 (read Win 7/8). Therefore, as above, for 1607+, you need to copy the ADMX file from Windows 10 itself to have full GPO settings available.